# Multiple Knockout components see the same properties

Tags: knockout.js

**UPDATE**
Interestingly it works properly if I embed the HTML into the template property of the ko.component.register function.

https://jsfiddle.net/h5rnqwu4/1/

```
ko.components.register('item-2', {
    viewModel: Item2,
    template: '<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="visible: $parent.activeView()===\'item-2\'"> <h1>Item 2</h1> <input data-bind="value: comment"/> <h3 data-bind="text: comment"></h3> </div>'
});
```

Maybe that's how it is supposed to work?

---

first things first...I've created a fiddle showing some sample code so you can see what is going wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/e427a7p2/1/

In essence I have two components, each of which have a *comment* property.  The issue is that they seem to be sharing the same comment property, and so when I change one of them the other changes too.

To replicate the issue carry out the following steps:

1. Click on Item 1 and note the contents of the input box and the text below.
2. Click on Item 2 and note the contents of the input box and the text below.
3. Go back to Item 1 (click on the header to get back) and change the text in the input box.  What should happen is that the text below changes, but it doesn't.
4. Go back to Item 2 (click on the header to get back) and note the contents of the input box and the text below.  It is the same as the input we changed in step 3.
5. Change the contents of the input box on Item 2 and you can see that the text below it changes.
6. Go back to Item 1 (click on the header to get back) and note that the contents of the input box are the same as you just changed them to.  The text below has still not changed.

So for some reason although they're meant to be separate viewModels they are sharing (kind-of) the comments property.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

The HTML for the components is as follows:

```
<div id="item-1">
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="with: Item1, visible: activeView() === 'item-1'">
        <h1>Item 1</h1>
        <input data-bind="value: comment" />
        <h3 data-bind="text: comment"></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="item-2">
    <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="with: Item2, visible: activeView() === 'item-2'">
        <h1>Item 2</h1>
        <input data-bind="value: comment" />
        <h3 data-bind="text: comment"></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JS is as follows:

```
var Item1 = function Item1() {
    var self = this;

    console.log(self);

    self.title = ko.observable('Item 1');
    self.comment = ko.observable('comment: item 1');
}

var Item2 = function Item2() {
    var self = this;

    console.log(self);

    self.title = ko.observable('Item 2');
    self.comment = ko.observable('comment: item 2');
}

ko.components.register('menu', {
    viewModel: Menu,
    template: {element: 'menu'}
});

ko.components.register('item-1', {
    viewModel: Item1,
    template: {element: 'item-1'}
});

ko.components.register('item-2', {
    viewModel: Item2,
    template: {element: 'item-2'}
});

var VM = function VM() {
    var self = this;

    self.activeView = ko.observable();

    Sammy(function() {
        this.get('/', function(context) {
            self.activeView('menu');
        });

        this.get('#/item-1', function(context) {
            self.activeView('item-1');
        });

        this.get('#/item-2', function(context) {
            self.activeView('item-2');
        });
    }).run();
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: You have got a typo in your html, both id="item-2" is used. That doesn't fix it btw.

Answer (score 0):

Items can be defined in html. Best way of doing that is in a script tag. This makes sure template can contain tables etc.

```
<script id="item-1" type="text/template">
  <div>markup here</div>
</script>
```

In your fiddle you are defining the templates(item-1 and item-2) body. Than you bind the view model to the whole document `ko.applyBindings(new VM());` this binds the ViewModel to your item templates and that is not valid.

Your html should look like this

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <item-1></item-1>
  </div>
  <div id="item-1">item template id</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // only bind view model to the container and not to the templates
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(),document.getElementById("container"));
</script>
</body>
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e427a7p2/2/